# How to choose branches from snapshot dependencies in custom builds

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

The TC docs basically imply that you can choose a branch in the Custom Build Dialog from branches that appear in your snapshot-dependencies, but I cannot get this to work.

In fact the list of branches I see neither appears to be from my build configuration, nor the snapshot-dependency. The docs also imply that branch tags will show up in the UI if you have branches in your snapshot-dependency, but they don't unless I attach the same VCS root.

In "Triggering a Custom Build" it says:

From [8.x docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Triggering+a+Custom+Build):

> If you have branches in your build configuration (***or in snapshot
>   dependencies of this build configuration***), you can choose a branch to
>   be used for the custom build in this dialog.

From [9.x docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Triggering+a+Custom+Build):

> The Build branch drop-down, available if you have branches in your
>   build configuration (***or in snapshot dependencies of this build
>   configuration***), allows choosing a branch to be used for the custom
>   build.

Both imply that branches from snapshot dependencies should show up in the Run Custom Build dialog. But they don't. After playing around with this for a while, I can only get the pretty branch tags to appear in the UI if my dependant project has the same VCS root attached (even though it doesn't even use any source in its build steps).

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something about TC?

I'm using TC 9.1, with git/branch specifications.